# React-Table - How to remove the 'Toggle sortBy' tooltip from the column header?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-table, react-table-v7

In the latest version (7.5.x) of React-Table, when using the Material-UI Table components, is there a way to remove the 'Toggle sortBy' tooltip from the column header?

[Two tooltips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIxbg.png)

I have a tooltip with the column header name. both tooltips appear upon hover.
Take a look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-easley-s8kbn)

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox example to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Adding `{...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps({ title: undefined }))}` did the trick.

Here's the updated [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/shy-pine-7umv9?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Just for reference, this is due to this line in React Table source code: https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/v7.6.3/src/plugin-hooks/useSortBy.js#L51

Answer (score 2):

Or just overwrite the title like in:

```
<span {...column.getGroupByToggleProps()} title="">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override it with your own label you can do this. You can also only show the label on columns that can be sorted.

```
<span {...column.getGroupByToggleProps()} title={column.canSort ? `Sort By ${column.id}` : ""}>
```